# App container for loading a HTML5 site

Tags: android, ios, iphone

there is a very famous app from Indeed

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.indeed.android.jobsearch&hl=de
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/job-search/id309735670?mt=8

For both OS, the App is only an native container, which loads the URL: http://de.indeed.com/m/?app=2.4%2CIphone

My question is: Is there some framework like Phonegap oder something else, where I can create for both OS only the container and load my HTML5 site in it? Or should I write one in Java and one in Swift so I can load the site after that?

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some framework like Phonegap oder something else, where I can create for both OS only the container and load my HTML5 site in it?

I dont know the answer for this question, since phonegap is already using HTML 5 as its programming language.

> should I write one in Java and one in Swift so I can load the site after that?

This is what i know should work. This is what people doing on my office :

1. They created a responsive web.
2. They created a native app (not **hybrid**), in other word : they use
   eclipse/xcode
3. The native app basically is just a full screen web view

With this, they successfully employ android & iOS native apps only with web view and upload it to their respective store.

Comment: Hi Blaze Tama, I am thinking to do the same thing. I will create in Java and Objectiv C the containers only and create a WebView and call the HTML5 web in it. Are there no restrictions for Apple, where they decline such Apps? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @NikoNik Sorry i dont understand about apple, because my office only create the android one - someone else created the apple. I think its better for you to create a new question regarding apple's policy. Good luck :)

Comment: There has to be something out there to address this issue. I'm looking for the same container.